# RXjs - How to wait for new value on observable A, every time observable B says its okay to start 'watching'

Tags: rxjs6

I have a stream of observableA, emitting regularly.

When observableB emits, I want to start watching ObservableA at that point, until it emits a value, capture it and then stop watching again.  Once more I will now wait until observableB emits again.  Rinse and repeat.

I can think of a couple of ways to do this, but none of them are very 'pretty'.

Is there a 'correct' way to do this in RXjs6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kind of depends on your exact use case here (ie if B emits twice before A emits once, do you want 2 A's or 1 A? Does order matter?), but this might work:

```
obsB$.pipe(
  switchMapTo(obsA$.pipe(first()))
);
```

just on every B emission, switch into A and take the first emission. Clean and simple. Could use `mergeMapTo` or `concatMapTo` if you need slightly 
different behaviors.